# Microsoft.Graph SDK SendMail As User - 400 - Unexpected Exception or Open navigation properties are not supported

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm working on an application that needs to send email notifications and reminders to users when they have actions to complete.  A user submits data, then the app notifies other users to perform actions in a specific order (i.e. User 1: Task 1, after Task 1 is complete, User 2: Task 2, etc.) - if a user is taking too long to perform their action, the system will remind them then defer to their manager (via a Windows service or similar).  Due to this, I can't send messages on behalf of the current signed in user - it needs to be able to send messages on its own.  It is preferred to send on behalf of the user that submitted the data, so subsequent users can reply directly to them.

I'm using the [Microsoft Graph Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) v1.10.0.  Running my code yields an aggregate exception ultimately boiling down to a code 400, code `"generalException"`, message `"Unexpected exception returned from the service."`  I've used LinqPad to look into the Graph objects, and attempted to reproduce the call in Postman, which yields a 400 with a message of `"Open navigation properties are not supported on OpenTypes. Property name: 'microsoft.graph.sendmail'."`

**More thorough details:**

- Application has Microsoft Graph -> `Send mail as any user`, `Read all groups`, `Read all users' full profiles` permissions.
- Calling `GraphServiceClient.Client.Users["MyUPN"].SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync()` yields a 400 general exception with `Unexpected exception returned from the service.` (Full code below)
- Looking at the request, I found it's calling `https://graph.windows.net:443/{{tenantId}}/users/{{MyUPN}}/microsoft.graph.sendMail?api-version=1.6` and attempted to make the same call via Postman (with a valid token), which yielded a 400 bad request with message `Open navigation properties are not supported on OpenTypes. Property name: 'microsoft.graph.sendMail'.`

Full Code:

```
String MyEmailAddress = "";
String MyUpn = "";
String TenantId = "";
String AppGuid = "";
String AppKey = "";

var sender = new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient()

{
    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress() { Address = MyEmailAddress }
};
var email = new Microsoft.Graph.Message
{
    Sender = sender,
    From = sender,
    Subject = "Test",
    Body = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody()
    {
        Content = "Test Body",
        ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Text
    }
};

email.ToRecipients = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Recipient>(){ sender };

email.BodyPreview = "Test Summary";


GraphSdk _Sdk = new GraphSdk(TenantId, AppGuid, AppKey);

// Where the error throws
await _Sdk.Client.Users[MyUpn].SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

As a test, I also tried `await _Sdk.Client.Users[MyUpn].Messages.Request().Top(20).GetAsync();` which yielded the same error.   Other Graph calls, like getting a user's groups or manager, work fine - this error only appears on email-related calls.

---

**Update 9/19/2018 AM**

It looks like I can get emails working if I use a certificate to generate the token instead of the Key -> Password; and call the Outlook API instead.  Unfortunately, that doesn't work through the GraphServiceClient and Graph API - it can use the certificate, and use the Outlook API base URL, but the `microsoft.graph.sendMail` action is just `sendMail` in the Outlook API.

For maintainability, I'd still like to get it all working under the Graph API so I'm still looking for an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point I had set the BaseUrl for the client to `https://graph.windows.net:443/{{tenantId}}`, possibly due to the varying branding over the past few years (Microsoft Graph vs Azure Graph).  Under current recommendations for the Microsoft.Graph it should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/` - which also appears to be the default value.

Additionally, I had to switch to using a certificate instead of the Azure-generated Key -> Password for the app.

Total working code is:

```
String AADTenantId = "";
String AppGuid = "";
String SenderAddress = "";
String SenderId = "";
String ToAddress = "";
String SubjectText = "";
String BodyText = "";
Byte[] Certificate = ...GetCertBytes...
String CertPassword = "";

var client = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
    async requestMessage =>
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AADTenantId}");
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Certificate, CertPassword);
        var clientAssertion = new ClientAssertionCertificate(AppGuid, cert);
        AuthenticationResult authresult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientAssertion);

        // Append the access token to the request
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authresult.AccessToken);
    }));

var sender = new Recipient()
{
    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress() { Address = SenderAddress }
};
var email = new Message
{
    Sender = sender,
    From = sender,
    Subject = SubjectText,
    Body = new ItemBody()
    {
        Content = BodyText,
        ContentType = BodyType.Text
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>() {
        new Recipient() { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = ToAddress }}
    }
};

await client.Users[SenderId].SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want send an email but get an 400 error.

Based on my test, we can use the following steps to send an email.

step1, we should get a `graphClient` which is a authenticated HttpClient.

The code like this:

```
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    string accessToken = await MsalAuthProvider.Instance.GetUserAccesstokenAsync();
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
                }));
        return graphServiceClient;
```

We can refer to [the simple code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample) in the official document.

step2, we can use the following code to send a mail:

```
public async Task<bool> SendAsync(EmailAddress toaddress)
    {
        var email = new Message
        {
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                Content = "Test for sending eamil ",
                ContentType = BodyType.Text,
            },
            Subject = "Test for sending eamil",
            ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                   EmailAddress = toaddress 
                }
            },
        };
        try
        {
            await _serviceClient.Me.SendMail(email).Request().PostAsync(); // the _serviceClient is the result in the step1.
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```